# Check and replace column values in R dataframe

Tags: r

I have multiple files to read in using R. I iterate through the files in a loop, obtain dataframes and then try to change values of a particular column. Examples of the R dataframes are as follows:

df_A:

```
ID  ZN
1   0
2   1
3   1
4   0
```

df_B:

```
ID  ZN
1   2
2   1
3   1
4   2
```

As shown above, the column 'ZN' for some dataaframes may have 0's and 1's and others dataframes have have 1's and 2's. What I want is - as I'm iterating through the files, I want to make changes only in the dataframes with column ZN having 1's and 2's like this: 1 to 0 and 2 to 1. Dataframes with ZN values as 0's and 1's will be left unchaged.

my attempt did not work:

```
if(dataframe$ZN > 1){
    dataframe$ZN<-recode(dataframe$ZN,"1=0;2=1")
  }
  else{
  dataframe$ZN
  }
```

Any solutions please?

Comment: Can there be `0` and `2` in same dataframe?

Comment: Just do `(df_A$ZN==0) + 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to decrement the value of `ZN` by one if we detect a single value of `2` anywhere in the column:

```
if (max(df_A$ZN) == 2) {
    df_A$ZN = df_A$ZN - 1
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen . Unfortunately, it didn't work as expected using the following code: files <- list.files('.', pattern='*.txt')

for(f in files){
  df <- read.table(f,header=TRUE, sep='\t')
  print(df)
  df$ZN <- ifelse(max(df$ZN) == 1,df$ZN - 1,df$ZN)
  print(df)
}

Comment: @RobJohn I have working code now.  I couldn't get it to work with `ifelse`, and in general using `if` statements in R is probably frowned upon, but if it fixes your problem this is the most important thing in the end.

Comment: It works now. I really appreciate your help @Tim Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two values i.e. 0 and 1, then

```
df_A$ZN <- (df_A$ZN==0) + 1
df_A$ZN
#[1] 2 1 1 2
```

---

Or using `case_when` for multiple values

```
library(dplyr)
df_A %>%
  mutate(ZN = case_when(ZN==0 ~2, TRUE ~ 1))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The code from Tim Biegeleisen now works for me.